# All the text in my android application gets blurred

Tags: android

I have an android application that works fine on my device. But when i install the application on Acer Iconia A500 tab, all the text gets blurred.

This seems to be an issue with different screen resolutions.

How can i resolve this issue?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How did you code your text views? What unit do you use? Do you have special layouts for tablets? We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use "sp" units to  set text size. But anyway getting blurred is wired effect

Comment: If I recall correctly, the official recommendation from the Android team is to use the `dip` unit.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig No, `sp` is basically the same thing as `dp` *(=`dip`)*. It just also takes the users font size preference into calculation and is therefore the best choice for font sizes - see [Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: Yes. I have used "sp" for textfields. But this seems to be a totally different issue. The dialog that i create also has got a zoom 4x effect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is getting scaled by the new zoom mode: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-mode-for-apps-on-large-screens.html

I don't know why they copied this from the iPad (which can run iPhone designed apps x2 zoomed) as it is a horrible feature.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the android documentation regarding supporting multiple screen resolutions.  It will be a big help to you:  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have added the same. But it does not make any difference